# I need an answer related to odoo

Tags: odoo-9

In odoo 9 we create our own template of home page but on this page we are unable to use the editor elements from the editor. It's color change to red when we hover on the structure elements

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

for this you need to define attribute customize_show="True" while defining the template like this -

```
<template id="custom_template" inherit_id="optional" customize_show="True">
.
.
.
</template>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply nut this is not working In console it showing error that  "Image-Text have not insert action: data-drop-near or data-drop-in"

Answer (score 0):

you get that error because your wrapper around your entire page is missing and id and a class on your general div, your code should look like this:

```
<div id="wrap" class="oe_structure oe_empty">
#your page code goes here
</div>
```

on the other hand `customize_show="True"` is an option on the templates to give the user the option to enable o disable templates on the frontend, this will display the template name with a toggle/checkbox on the website editor menu "Customize"

best regards.